# Neo4J DB modeling - relations and parent nodes

Tags: model, neo4j

Good morning,

I am starting to move from relational DB to Neo and thus transfering my "table-thinking" into the graph world. Thinking about a model to represent my task module I need to put the following entities into relation:

- Customer
- Task
- User

So I came up with this idea:

```
(CUSTOMER)-[:GENERATES]->(TASK) 
(USER)-[:IS_ASSIGNED_TO]->(TASK)
```

I was pondering when I am going to query this I would label each task node with the label TASK and having a status as property, e.g. closed, open etc.

Looking up now all open tasks could been solved by

```
MATCH (t:TASK {status:"open"}) -[:IS_ASSIGNED_TO]-> (u:USER) 
MATCH (c:Customer) -[:GENERATES]-> (t:TASK)
RETURN t.number as task_number, c.name as customer_name, u.name as user_name
```

While creating the nodes and relationships I was wondering if I just create a node for task, one for user and one for customer and connect them like the model above or if I would need to have something like a "parent-node" of each node type e.g. a GENERAL_USER, a GENERAL_TASK and a GENERAL_CUSTOMER and having connected each single node to that parent as well with a relationship that covers the current status. Idea behind was when I want to have open tasks I could maybe easier just start with the GENERAL_TASK node and look up all relations to tasks that have the status OPEN instead of looking for each node that might be in the DB somewhere. Is that faster than asking the DB to return all TASK nodes that have a property status with the content OPEN (even if that is indexed)?

Would be happy to have some input to understand better how to model the DB and the relations. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

So I think you're thinking in the right direction here.  When choosing how best to model the data, the query pattern matters a lot.

In general, neo4j is set up to make traversing relationships cheap.  So as a general rule of thumb, it's going to be cheaper to navigate across relationships than it will be to scan all of your nodes for ones with a particular property value.

If a certain status grouping of tasks is going to be something you query on frequently, then linking tasks to that "class" of tasks in your model probably makes sense.  Just make sure that you maintain those links correctly.  One of the downsides is that it would be possible for a node to be linked to two different statuses (which might not make sense under your model) whereas if the node had a status "property", then it could only have one value at a time.   As your tasks get processed, their status will change, and your code will need to make sure for example that all Tasks are linked to one and only one status.

Let's say you have a discrete variable (that is, a variable that can only take one of a fixed set of values, like say a state code, or a "status" flag).  When should you make that a separate node, and when should you make that a node property?  There are no hard and fast answers, but here are a few guidelines:

**Things that would suggest it should be a node**

1. Frequent need to filter large result sets by this particular value
2. It's relevant to more than one node type (i.e. tasks have a status, but users might be linked to certain statuses too)

**Things that would suggest it should be a property**

1. It's only relevant to one node type
2. The number of values is very small (i.e. < 5)
3. Infrequent querying based on that property

Comment: Thanks FrobberOfBits, that helps me to think on and check my module for the points you mentioned. It feels on the first touch to do status as property as it is only relevant for that type of nodes. So that means having the status as part of the relationship should be skipped in favor of having status on nodes (be it a special one or the data node) - and there is no need to have a MAIN NODE to connect them but having single nodes that are only connected to the customer - so querying then for a status on the nodes (indexed) - did I got that right?

Comment: In past versions of neo4j, people had a "main node" that they used as an index of sorts.  I don't think that's as necessary now, since there are labels and indexes.  It's not that slow to do `MATCH (p:Person {id: "5"}) because you're giving neo4j two ways to do the lookup fast: by label and by property (indexed).

Comment: Great, so my worries are obsolete - thanks for calm my mind :)